# Vim buffer position change on window split (annoyance)

Tags: vim

This is really starting to get on my nerves, which is weird because it's such a small issue.

Let's say I start (g)vim 7.3 (windows OR linux) with no plugins/no vimrc. I open a longer file, scroll down halfway. I position my cursor at the bottom of the main window. I open a vertical split window (CTRL+W v).

What happens next is killing me. The cursor and the line it's on (previously at the bottom of the original window) *jump up* to the top of the window. The new window on the right has the original position where the line the cursor is on was in the original window.

[image]

My question: How do I keep vim from changing the cursor position of the window I split? Honestly, I wouldn't care at all if the position changed in the *new* window, but the fact that splitting changes the original window is making me want to tear my hair out.

It used to be completely ignorable. Then I got kind of annoyed. Then I slowly started getting really annoyed. Now it's starting to make me furious. Any help/tricks/hacks are greatly appreciated!!

EDIT: My vim build options for both Windows and Linux (happening on both):

Windows:

```
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs
-dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +gettext/dyn -hangul_input +iconv/dyn
+insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape
+multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme -netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra -perl
+persistent_undo -postscript +printer -profile -python -python3 +quickfix
+reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime
+statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white
-tcl -tgetent -termresponse +textobjects +title -toolbar +user_commands
+vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore
+wildmenu +windows +writebackup -xfontset -xim -xterm_save -xpm_w32
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32   -DFEAT_CSCOPE       -DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400  /Fo.\ObjC/ /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_BIG /Fd.\ObjC/ /Zi
Linking: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:console /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib  libcmt.lib   user32.lib             /PDB:vim.pdb -debug
```

Linux:

```
-arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-conceal +cryptv -cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff 
+digraphs +dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi 
+file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext 
-hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall 
+linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname 
+mouse +mouseshape -mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm 
-mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg 
-osfiletype +path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile 
+python -python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup +X11 -xfontset +xim 
+xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng14     -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lXt -lncurses -lacl -lgpm     -L/usr/lib64/python2.6/config -lpython2.6 -lpthread -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with Vim 7.3 on Linux, even when running `vim -u NONE -U NONE`. Does removing "mswin.vim" from the Vim runtime directory make the problem go away?

Comment: Neither can I reproduce this behaviour in a linux box with `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3`

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give it removing mswin.vim a shot. Like I said, happens in linux too. EDIT: removed mswin.vim, same issue. Is there a way to compare build options?

Comment: +1 for your careful explanation of the problem and annoyance in such state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can reproduce the behaviour, which with your description would (at first sight) *appear* to be a bug, indeed. But I noticed the following things:

- `:vert split` has the same behaviour as <kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>
- `:debug ver split` (... `cont`) confirmed there wasn't an obvious script/autocommand interfering
- It only happens on the first time split. In other words, this is a workaround: <kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>
- the cursor does in fact *not* move in the *original* window. The 'new window' appears on the left (which you name the original window). This cannot be shown with `:echo winnr()` or similar, but you can make it more apparent by doing e.g. `:vert new` instead of `:vert split`: the new, empty window appears on the left side.

Instead of this, you might trick the split to have 'second split' behaviour by doing something 'useless' before

```
 :tabnew|bwipeout
```

Now, <kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> has the desired behaviour first time around.

#### TL;DR

1. it was not a bug (your expectations on what was the *new* window were off)
2. you can work around it by creating another window before.

---

#### *Other background*

1. The `splitright`, `splitbelow` options

   > can be used to control (to an extent) where newly created (split) windows appear
2. The `winrestview()` function

   > Can be used to explicitely restore the exact view of a window. Use it like so:
   >
   > ```
   >   :let savex=winsaveview()
   > ```
   >
   > `savex` now contains something like *`{'lnum': 1, 'leftcol': 0, 'col': 0, 'topfill': 0, 'topline': 1, 'coladd': 0, 'skipcol': 0, 'curswant': 0}`* describing the state of the current view.
   >
   > *(do stuff, like <kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>)*
   >
   > ```
   >   :call winrestview(savex)
   > ```
   >
   > This is obviously a lot more flexible but you might not need it.

Comment: You hit (I believe) the answer in a roundabout way:  1) the root issue is that the OP expected the new window to appear on the right, but it appeared on the left, and 2) this behavior can be reversed with the `set splitright` command.

Comment: @DavidPope I think your summary is correct and a little more clear than this answer to be honest, but +1 for the answer as well.

Comment: Ah, perfect!! I was looking all over for something like splitright. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @DavidPope: I was interested in describing the phenomenon better. There is some unexpected behaviour on the first split, and various workarounds actually work better than `splitright`, it depends on what the OP prefers, really. Using `^Wv^Wc^Wv`, e.g. results in both windows being at the same cursor location, and the cursor not jumping to the rightmost window. Not having to set `splitright` might be preferred. Lastly, it _is_ peculiar to see that subsequent splits with `^Wv` seem to do what the OP wants anway. Call it roundabout, I call it thorough (or curious).

Comment: @sehe Agreed; I wasn't criticizing, just summarizing.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on a Windows machine with `gvim` and could reproduce your problem, here is a workaround that worked for me adding next commands to `vimrc` (I got it with `:e $MYVIMRC`):

```
set splitright

function MySplit()
    vsplit
    execute "normal \<C-w>\<C-w>"
endfunction

nmap <C-w>v :call MySplit()<CR>
```

Comment: There are simpler workarounds, not requiring config changes. Consider using `nnoremap` to avoid interference with other scripts/mappings. Also, the slashes seem out of place.