# Is there a way for ctrl-6 to jump back to EXACT the same page content of the previous file

Tags: vim

I used ctrl-6 to jump between two files and compare these two files page by page, But each time when I switch back, the page content is changed. That is, a new page with previous cursor line in the middle of screen now is shown instead.

Is there a way to keep the page position in the screen unchanged when I switched back.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest using tabs (<kbd>C-PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>C-PgDn</kbd> to switch)?

You can always start by doing <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>C-^</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Otherwise see this odler answer of mine for hints on restoring cursor positions:

- [After a :windo, how do I get the cursor back where it was?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984032/after-a-windo-how-do-i-get-the-cursor-back-where-it-was/9989348#9989348)
- [Vim buffer position change on window split (annoyance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625028/vim-buffer-position-change-on-window-split-annoyance/9626591#9626591)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you're looking for, but just in case:  For a different approach to the task you're doing (visually comparing two files), see `:help scrollbind`.  You would do `:set scrollbind` in two side-by-side windows and open one file in each, then scroll through them together, linked.  See also `vimdiff` for even more functionality.