# In vim: how can I run `z.` automatically after opening a buffer?

Tags: vim

Whenever I open a split or cycle through git's history with `.:Glog` my cursor always ends up at the top or bottom of the page. I always hit `z.` to align the text and I was looking for an automatic way of doing this.

Comment: Do you mean that you use `zz` to move the current line to center? And do you only want this functionality for git log filetypes, or for _all files_?

Comment: I'd like this for all files. Also, what's the difference between `zz` and `z.`? I use `z.` but they seem very similar.

Comment: `z` alone does nothing for me, and I don't think that's a default binding.  `zz` is a default binding and positions the current line in the middle of the window.

Comment: Do you want this to happen only when opening something in a split, or _any_ time you open any buffer?

Comment: Any time I open a buffer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think I figured it out. The command is `zz` but the `.` repeats your last command. So, `z.` gets interpreted as `zz`.

Comment: @spinlock Actually, `z.` is a real command, not a repeated `zz`. The difference between `z.` and `zz` is that `zz` leaves cursor in the same column, while `z.` puts it at first non-blank in the line. You can read about it in `:help z.`

Comment: Hmm @spinlock - [I just found this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625028/vim-buffer-position-change-on-window-split-annoyance) which is maybe describing the same thing you experience and has a thorough answer...

Comment: I misread your `z.` several times as plain `z`, which was the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the link from @michaelberkowski I was able to figure out the following workaround for vertical splits:

```
" Open vertical split with identical configuration to parent
function! AwesomeSplit()
  :let savex=winsaveview()
  vsplit
  :call winrestview(savex)
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>vs :call AwesomeSplit()<CR>
```

For navigating buffers with `:.Glog` I use vim-unimpared from Tim Pope. The shortcuts I use -- `]q` and `[q` -- are just aliases for `:cnext` and `:cprevious` so I'll see if I can create a patch for vim-unimpared using `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()`.